# Algorithm for finding graph levels

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have found an algorithm to separate a graph in its different levels, but as I don't know its name, and I couldn't find it anywhere else I don't trust it 100%. It goes like this:

```
Given de adjacency matrix of G = (V,E), M:

i = 1
while M ≠ 0:
    Level i = vertices such that their rows and columns in M are all 0.
    M = M - rows and columns which are all 0.
    i = i + 1
```

(M != 0 means M is not empty)

Does this always work? Does it have a name or can I find it anywhere else?

EDIT:

This is the definition of "level" that I have for a directed graph: A set of vertices N is in a higher level than other set of vertices K if no vertex in N is reachable from any vertex in K.

Here's the example from where I found this pseudocode. There's the original graph (middle), the vertices on each level (left), and another graph which I'm not quite sure why it's there, but its clear that its exactly the same as the original just rearranged to make clear the "partition" into different "levels"

[image: picture]

I posted this mainly because this definition of level, the algorithm and the example are on a note written by some other student I don't know, and she didn't put any bibliographic references or anything, and I'm studying for an exam on my own because I didn't go to the classes... and these topics are not so easy to Google due to different namings, etc.

This somehow reminds me of topological order too...maybe it has something to do with that?

Comment: what do you meant with m!=0 ?

Comment: Possibly what you call "graph levels" are more commonly called the connected components of the graph $G$.  The pseudocode presented is not entirely convincing as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik $!=$ means $\neq$.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with [dominators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory))?

Comment: That's it! Anyway, what I found about dominators say nothing close to this algorithm I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

What you define there isn't even a partial ordering, The set {A} is higher than {G} (G can't reach A), and {G} is higher than {A} (A can't reach G), so your levels aren't actually correct A>G, G>A. It is a pre-ordering but there's not as much one can assume about pre-orders.

Also that algorithm doesn't halt on
$1-> 2-> 3$
which has the adjacency matrix

$010\\001\\000$

By your algorithm, level 1 = {}, next matrix is,

$10\\01$

And then this loops forever.

So no this algorithm as you describe does not give the results you desire.

Edit:

Assuming this is a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG), the algorithm is as follows,

level 1 = all Nodes with no edges in

level n+1 = (all nodes reachable by level n) -(disjoint) (all nodes reachable by any other node in level n)

Comment: Actually, I think it should be like this :" Level i = vertices such that their columns in M are all 0" (not rows). Then remove the columns AND the rows corresponding to those vertices (even if a row wasn't all 0s). And now that I think about it, it probably is just another name for "topological ordering"

Comment: I suspect that's isomorphic to the algorithm I presented, but much more code-able. The BIG IMPORTANT FACT there is you are dealing with a directed acyclic graph, that wasn't stated in the original problem and is fairly important.

Answer (score 1):

From *Introduction to algorithms, Thomas Cormen*: "... Another way to perform **topological sorting** on a directed acyclic graph is to repeatedly find a vertex of in-degree 0, output it, and remove it and
all of its outgoing edges from the graph.' 
Which is precisely what the pseudocode I wrote does. So I will just forget about the word "level" and perform a topological sorting, which is the same.